# How can I store more than 5 MB on an iPhone web app?

Tags: iphone, database, offline, web-applications

I am working on a magazine/portfolio application that is intended to be readable offline, saved as an icon on the home page.

This is using a lot of images, but while I can keep the images down to a respectable size (200 KB or less, with alterations for iPhone vs iPad) the amount for the page surpasses the 5 MB limit for a web app cache.

I have tried the cache manifest, but if the device is turned off or I clear the cache (which I do a lot while developing) the information is gone forever (and does not get resaved if I visit the bookmarked site while online again).

I am exploring the use of base64 to store the smaller icons in a CSS file, but am not sure about how to build a local storage database for the other information (backgrounds, images, text, etc) that will be persistent without being tied to the Safari cache.

Is this even possible?

(The project is intended to be an open source publishing engine, so more people can create digital 'zines for the iPad.)

Comment: Not sure if this is a new feature or not, but now it will ask the user to increase the offline storage limit once it hits the 5MB limit.

Answer (score 2):

you can't...

if you are limiting your application to a web application on the iphone, then your options are limited to what is provided on the device. I believe sqlitedb with mobile safari is limited to 5MB.

You can look into technology like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) which provides a wrapper around HTML5 web based applications on multiple platforms. This wrapper will give you access to the native device and then you could store additional data on the device in flat files on the native database without the 5MB limit

Comment: You could also look into the Titanium Platform at http://www.appcelerator.com/ We tried it at work for awhile about 8 months ago and while it was very compelling and fairly rich with features, it just wasn't stable enough to fit our needs at the time. I do believe it's matured a considerable amount since then, however.

Comment: @jocull I did not mention Appcelerator because it is not a web container, Gerry would have to completely rewrite his application to use that technology.. he has a webApp

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. I didn't realize that PhoneGap was so much simpler. Maybe we should have looked at that in the past!

Comment: For this portfolio, I may have to look at phonegap. Or appcelerator (I am looing at cappucino or sproutcore as well. this will be the third time I have changed frameworks)

Comment: @Gerry Straathof if you already have an web app/website, just drop it into a PhoneGap project and it should just work.

Comment: Phonegap is what we will be using for the application to be an app on the app store (I wanted to avoid that if I could) but the size limit has expanded to 10M so I can use create the app/magazine that way. I wanted it to be as easy as clicking on a web link to get to the magazine with the option to save it for later.Much easier than the rigamarole of going through the app store.